# Error: cannot import name 'BaseBackend' from 'qiskit.providers'

Tags: qiskit

when I try to use a quantum instance I get the error below.
I'm using qiskit 0.37.0 and qiskit-aqua 0.9.5.
Any hint suggested?
Thanks in advance

````
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/gl/v7sz8_9j0nqcpxrr79rjtq7w0000gn/T/ipykernel_64860/3839405800.py in <module>
      7 print(provider.backends())
      8 
----> 9 from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
     10 
     11 backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_manila')

/Applications/miniconda3/envs/eelbrain/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/__init__.py in <module>
     74 from .missing_optional_library_error import MissingOptionalLibraryError
     75 from .aqua_globals import aqua_globals
---> 76 from .quantum_instance import QuantumInstance
     77 from .algorithms import QuantumAlgorithm
     78 from ._logging import (QiskitLogDomains,

/Applications/miniconda3/envs/eelbrain/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/aqua/quantum_instance.py in <module>
     19 import numpy as np
     20 
---> 21 from qiskit.providers import Backend, BaseBackend
     22 from qiskit.transpiler import CouplingMap, PassManager
     23 from qiskit.transpiler.layout import Layout

ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseBackend' from 'qiskit.providers' (/Applications/miniconda3/envs/eelbrain/lib/python3.9/site-packages/qiskit/providers/__init__.py)```
````

Comment: The import error coming from qiskit.aqua is what's wrong in my opinion. It's been months since aqua is not updated and supported anymore in qiskit, see this https://qiskit.org/documentation/stable/0.32/aqua_tutorials/Qiskit%20Algorithms%20Migration%20Guide.html. It is quite old as well but it will give you clues as to what to replace aqua tools with.

Comment: Lena, your suggestion has been very helpful: problem solved. Thank you so much for taking time to help me
Andrea

Comment: @AndreaMameli I am facing the same problem. Please suggest a way to resolve it. I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. The problem here is with qiskit version you are using. use qiskit 0.31.0 as BaseBackend is in this version.
to install this version simply run

pip install qiskit==0.31.0